# sql query to show results vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

How to transform this:

```
ID   Name    Description
1    Test1a   TestDesc1a
1    Test1b   TestDesc1b
2    Test2a   TestDesc2a
2    Test2b   TestDesc2b
```

into this:

```
ID   Column          1            2
1    Name          test1a       test1b
1    Description   testDesc1a   testDesc1b
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in SQL? How are you using this data once you get it out of the database? It might be easier to perform this transformation on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question to solve, however the output specified is not proper/ conflicting. Below is similar solution which you can try

**Sample Table creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
[Id] [int] NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

**Inserting sample values:**

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (1,'Test1a','TestDesc1a')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (2,'Test1b','TestDesc1b')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (3,'Test2a','TestDesc2a')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (4,'Test2b','TestDesc2b')
```

**Query to get the desired output using Pivot:**

```
SELECT  'Name' AS [Column], [1], [2],[3],[4]
FROM
(SELECT Name, id from TestTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(Max(Name) FOR ID IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])) AS PT

UNION

SELECT  'Description' AS [Column], [1], [2],[3],[4]
FROM
(SELECT  id,[Description] from TestTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(Max([Description]) FOR ID IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])) AS PT
ORDER BY [Column] DESC
```

**OutPut:**

```
Column         1           2          3           4
Name           Test1a      Test1b     Test2a      Test2b
Description    TestDesc1a  TestDesc1b TestDesc2a  TestDesc2b
```

Hope this helps to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static `PIVOT` if you only are going to have a few columns but I am guessing that you will have more than 2 IDs so you will probably want to use a Dynamic `PIVOT` for this query.  Using a dynamic pivot will allow you to have more than the two ids you provided, it will grab all of the Ids from the table and then `PIVOT`:

```
create table temp
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10),
    description varchar(20)
)

insert into temp values (1, 'Test1a', 'TestDesc1a')
insert into temp values (1, 'Test1b', 'TestDesc1b')
insert into temp values (2, 'Test2a', 'TestDesc2a')
insert into temp values (2, 'Test2b', 'TestDesc2b')


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.id) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ''Name'' as [Column], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select id
                    , name
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(name)
                for id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            UNION 
            SELECT ''Description'' as [Column], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select id
                    , description
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(description)
                for id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

Results:

```
Column          1             2
Description     TestDesc1b    TestDesc2b
Name            Test1b        Test2b
```